# Iceland poppies

Tags: transplanting, perennials

I have a couple plants of Iceland poppies that bloomed back in the fall. I’d like to transplant them into a different container but I’m not sure if they can handle being moved/if it’s the right time for that or if they’ll even bloom again. Two plants are still looking alright, and there are little leaves sprouting up. Would those be ok to transplant too? [image]

Answer (score 1):

They are perennial plants, but they are fairly short lived and usually grown as annuals (sow the seed in spring for flowers in the same year) or biennials (sow the seed later in the year, so they flower earlier in the next year).

If yours are starting into growth again after winter you can transplant them now if you want to try it, but don't be disappointed if they don't do well.